# Start one RxJava stream after another one (unrelated) finishes

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

I have two RxJava streams that are unrelated to each other. I'll call them stream A and stream B. The two streams are independently started. When I go to start stream B, it needs to know whether stream A is still running. If it is, it must wait until stream A finishes. If stream A is not running, stream B can start. Once stream B is running, it should not be possible to start stream A until stream B has completed.

NOTE: When stream A completes, it only starts stream B if stream B needs to be run. Likewise, when stream B completes, it only starts stream A if it needs to be run.

I'm not sure if these two streams should be combined into a single stream or kept separate with other programming features used to coordinate when each stream can start. Perhaps there is something in the Kotlin language that makes doing this better than RxJava? Having a single stream is probably a good solution but only if it's not overly complex.

Comment: Just for me to understand, why would `A.flatMap { B }` not work for you?

Comment: "A" may not even be running. If it's not, you wouldn't even get to the part of the stream that deals with B using flatMap. Even if you were to start A, you would have to include code that bypasses its functionality. A is unrelated to B. It should not be required to execute A in order to get to B.

Comment: I see, thanks! I don't think I have any idea aside from maintaining some state, which sounds horrible to me. I'll let others answer.

Comment: what type of streams are these ? single, observable, etc?